# Sip Calls are not working in Android jelly bean

Tags: android

Sip calls are not working in Android jelly bean version. but the same code is working on Ice cream sandwich version. In jelly bean getting errors "sip registration failed" and "Failed to create sip session, network unavailable". I checked this application in Nexus jelly bean version tablet.

Here is my code. please any body help me...!

**code**:

```
SipProfile.Builder builder = new SipProfile.Builder(name, domain);
builder.setPassword(password);
me = builder.build();
Intent i = new Intent();
i.setAction("android.SipDemo.INCOMING_CALL");


PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(SipRegActivity.this, 0,i,Intent.FILL_IN_DATA);
manager.open(me, pi, null);

updateStatus("is opened ::  "+manager.isOpened(me.getUriString()));

manager.setRegistrationListener(me.getUriString(),new SipRegistrationListener() {

public void onRegistering(String localProfileUri) {
    updateStatus("SipRegistering ... ");
}

public void onRegistrationDone(String localProfileUri,long expiryTime) {
    updateStatus("SipRegistering done ... ");
}

        public void onRegistrationFailed(String localProfileUri, int errorCode,String errorMessage) {

    }
});

initiateCall();

public void initiateCall() {

    audioManager = (AudioManager) getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);

    try {
        SipSession.Listener sessionListener = new SipSession.Listener(){
            @Override
            public void onCalling(SipSession session) {

                String callId = session.getCallId();

            }

        };
        SipAudioCall.Listener listener = new SipAudioCall.Listener() {

            @Override
            public void onCallEstablished(SipAudioCall call) {

                updateStatus("Call is Established");
            }

            @Override
            public void onRinging(SipAudioCall call, SipProfile caller) { 
                super.onRinging(call, caller);
            }

            @Override
            public void onRingingBack(SipAudioCall call) {

                super.onRingingBack(call);

                 updateStatus("Ringing"+call.getState());

            }

            @Override
            public void onCallEnded(SipAudioCall call) {
                updateStatus("Call Ended.");


            }
        };


        SipSession ss = manager.createSipSession(me, sessionListener);
        call = manager.makeAudioCall(me.getUriString(),peerproile, listener, 120);
        call.startAudio();
```

I am also given permissions.

And  also checked isVoipSupported() and isApiSupported(). These methods returns true.

Comment: Ru sure you have give 0* in ...getBroadcast(SipRegActivity.this, *,i,Intent.FILL_IN_DATA);

Answer (score 1):

Its not depend of the Android OS ICS or JB its depend on your physical devices.

Not all Android-powered devices support VOIP calls using SIP. You should always call `isVoipSupported()` to verify that the device supports VOIP calling and `isApiSupported()` to verify that the device supports the SIP APIs.

[Ref Here:](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/sip.html#requirements)